# Need to fix PHP mailer error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am implementing mail functionality by using PHP mailer. 
The code is not working on online but its working on local machine. On local machine code sends the mail successfully but on online website it is showing following error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: ()
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Code is:

```
<?php
    include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

    $mail1 = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail1->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail1->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail1->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail1->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail1->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail1->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail1->IsHTML(true);
    $mail1->Username = "yourmail@gmail.com";
    $mail1->Password="password";        
    $mail1->SetFrom("yourmail@gmail.com");
    $mail1->Subject = "Working";
    $mail1->Body ="Hi, you got email";
    $mail1->AddAddress("yourmail2@gmail.com"); 
    $mail1->Send(); 
?>
```

Comment: have you tried port 587 ?

Comment: no. what is that? do you mean port 465 is not working?

Comment: Try $mail1->Port =587

Answer (score -2):

First you have to edit the "php.ini" To find this file display the phpinfo by using following code from the WAMP server. Create one php file and add this content.

```
<?php
     echo phpinfo();
?>
```

There search for "Loaded Configuration File" That will be the path to your php.ini.

In this file remove the ;(semi colon) given to extension=php_openssl.dll.

After downloading PHPMailer package
    Extract Copy the full folder into your project folder.
    Use the doc folder for help. In test folder there is one file called testemail.php.
    Change the parameter as your need. (Example given below).
    Then in the browser type 127.0.0.1/PHPMailer/test/testemail.php.
    Then it will show successful message if email sent, else it will give error message.

Example:

```
//add these codes if not written
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;

//You have to change these parameters to your requirements.


$mail->Username = “abc@gmail.com”; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password = “abcdefgh”; // GMAIL password
//..code ... There are many other functions to attach file etc.. For that refer doc file.
$mail->AddAddress(“destination@gmail.com”,”Nick name”);
```